# Простая инициализация ApplicationContext в SpringFramework

Tags: spring, java

Здравствуйте. У меня такой тривиальный вопрос. В спринге есть возможность поднять контекст, просто передав `xml` с бинами в аннотацию подобным образом:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/my-config.xml"}).
```

Такое используется для запуска `JUnit` тестов. Вопрос в следующем - можно ли подобное сделать и для обычного приложения, не `JUnit`, то есть без написания `java-кода` с созданием класса, в котором хранится `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`? То есть создать контекст сразу из `xml`, и потом гонять `@Required`, `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотите, чтобы можно было задать, скажем, контекст, бин и метод, с которого начать приложение и все - запускаем (запускать, предположительно, нужно будет что-то стороннее)? То, что вы ищите, называется сервером в его самой упрощенной форме. [Вот](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?52324-Best-practice-to-build-non-web-server-using-Spring), например, была такая идея на спрингфоруме, возможно, они чего-то и достигли. Но мне кажется, что вряд ли есть сколь известный подобный проект - хотя бы потому, что и писать-то там особо немного, и скопипастить двухстрочный `main()` очень быстро, а если что-то начинает развиваться, то превращается уже во что-то большее.

UPD. Простейший загрузчик контекста.

```
public class ContextLoader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String configLocation = args[0];
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configLocation);
    }
}
```

Запускаем `java -cp [указываем все нужные пути] ContextLoader classpath:ctx.xml`. Из IDE еще проще.

Comment: Нет.в моем примере @ContextConfiguration - лежит в пакете который отвечает за поддержку JUnit тестирования. Грубо говоря я интересовался есть ли такой же @ContextConfiguration но не для тестов. В документации по 3 спрингу нашел только поднятие контекста через ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. Я спрашиваю к тому что если мне нужно поднять 2 несчастных бина то зачем мне лишний раз создавать java код с инициализацией контекста

Comment: Ну да, я так и понял. Т.е. "есть ли такой класс (в самом спринге, например), который содержит метод `main()`, который просканирует указанные ему пакеты на наличие специфичной аннотации и инициализирует таким образом контекст". Если не важно именно использование аннотации, то вы можете написать это сами (см. UPD).

Comment: Так и сделал. Спасибо